# Accuracy not increasing when running multiple LinearRegressions tests

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I made a very simple program, that takes columns of data from a csv file, here is a short preview of the file data:

```
,matchId,blue_win,blueGold,blueMinionsKilled,blueJungleMinionsKilled,blueAvgLevel,redGold,redMinionsKilled,redJungleMinionsKilled,redAvgLevel,blueChampKills,blueHeraldKills,blueDragonKills,blueTowersDestroyed,redChampKills,redHeraldKills,redDragonKills,redTowersDestroyed
0,3493250918.0,0,24575.0,349.0,89.0,8.6,25856.0,346.0,80.0,9.2,6.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,12.0,2.0,0.0,1.0
1,3464936341.0,0,27210.0,290.0,36.0,9.0,28765.0,294.0,92.0,9.4,20.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,19.0,2.0,0.0,0.0
2,3428425921.0,1,32048.0,346.0,92.0,9.4,25305.0,293.0,84.0,9.4,17.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,11.0,0.0,0.0,4.0
3,3428347390.0,0,20261.0,223.0,60.0,8.2,30429.0,356.0,107.0,9.4,7.0,0.0,0.0,3.0,16.0,3.0,0.0,0.0
4,3428350940.0,1,30217.0,376.0,110.0,9.8,23889.0,334.0,60.0,8.8,16.0,3.0,0.0,0.0,8.0,0.0,0.0,2.0
5,3494458885.0,1,25470.0,362.0,82.0,9.2,22856.0,319.0,86.0,8.8,9.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,7.0,1.0,0.0,0.0
6,3463320642.0,1,25391.0,350.0,96.0,9.2,23236.0,345.0,80.0,8.6,8.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,5.0,1.0,0.0,1.0
...
```

I drop the unnecessary columns and run tests with 30% data used as test data to predict the accuracy of blue team winning the game:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pd.read_csv('MatchTimelinesFirst15.csv', delimiter=',')

predict = "blue_win"

df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
df = df.drop('redDragonKills', axis=1)
df = df.drop('blueDragonKills', axis=1)
# print(df.describe())

x = np.array(df.drop([predict], axis=1))
y = np.array(df[predict])


for _ in range(500):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.30)

    # print('{0}, {1}'.format(type(x_train), x_train))

    linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()

    # trains model
    linear.fit(x_train, y_train)

    acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)

    print('Accuracy: {0}'.format(acc))
```

But my accuracy wont increase even tho training it through a loop 500 times? I keep getting the same range of results:

```
Accuracy: 0.39030223064480596
Accuracy: 0.3980014684661366
Accuracy: 0.3840247556358104
Accuracy: 0.3939949181269252
Accuracy: 0.38657487661026535
Accuracy: 0.3950506154649621
Accuracy: 0.3925506648304995
...
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, also on improvements since i am very new to python and machine learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not training the model any further by using your loop. You start fresh every 500 times, only difference is the random initialisation of you train-test split.

As for improvements of your classifier, I would steer away from Linear Regression. Regression is not the same thing as classification. Classification will predict categorical class labels and regression predicts a continuous quantity.

Since you want to find out when the blue team wins, you have a binary classification problem. Either the blue team wins or it doesn't.

Try classification models like an [SVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.svm).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, i will definitely look into SVM instead :-)

Comment: Moreover, it is not a good practice use the test set for model selection, because in that way you are using it for learning. You can split further the dataset creating a validation set, or apply other techniques like LOO (Leave-one-out) cross-validation or K-fold cross-validation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Andrea, that is above my current knowledge, but i will read up on it, and try to adjust.
Thank you very much for the feedback.